# Can the "start at" value be saved in a Handbrake preset?

Tags: video, video-conversion, handbrake

I regularly have videos that I want to clip 16 seconds off the front of. I've finally figured out how to do this with Handbrake (the main source panel with it's "frames/seconds x through y" fields).

Given that my videos always seem to be 23.98fps, and that I want 16 seconds and change, being able to chop off the first 390-398 is very useful (I've yet to fine-tune just how many exactly). I would like to create another preset that included this as the start time.

When I attempt to do this, though, it does not work. Even with the new preset whenever I open another video for conversion, this reverts back to frame 1.

Is it possible to save this as a preset? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The "x through y fields" specify parameters for processing the input file. Presets specify parameters for the output file. So no, it's not possible to save these parameters as a preset.

You can utilize the the command line interface for Handbrake to accomplish this. For example, you have input.avi that you want to encode, starting at 390 frames, using the "normal" profile:

HandBrakeCLI -i input.avi -o output.mp4 --preset="Normal" --start-at frame:390

Also, if you want 16 seconds trimmed from the beginning, you can try "--start-at duration:16", which should be frame-rate independent.

Comment: I don't suppose that command line switch will work in the "advanced" field of HandbrakeGUI? As for the duration, it's just a little over 16 seconds but 17 is too much.

Comment: The advanced field affects the output stream, and will not affect the input stream (which is what you want to modify).  You might want to check out some alternative front-ends for Handbrake, there may be an alternative that meets your needs.